# MySQL - Select record with date closest from table and join to primary data set

Tags: mysql, join, channel

I am trying to create a data set which associates the correct marketing channel with a certain completed application and am having a VERY hard time figuring out the best way to do it.

I have 3 tables:

1. Table#1: Contact Info;
2. Table#2: Application Info;
3. Table#3: Channel Tracking History Info

The relevant fields in the tables referenced above are:

Table#1: `ID_table_1`

Table#2: `ID_Table_1` , `Application_Created_Date_Time_Tbl_2`

Table#3: `ID_Table_1` , `Channel_Update_Created_Date_Time_Tbl_3` , `Channel_Tracking_info`

(Note: all 3 tables are joined on `ID_Table_1` column)

`Table#1` is where the persons personal information is stored along with the last marketing channel they visited our site from. My problem is I need to know which channel they came in from when the completed an application, `Table#2`.  In order to do that I need to select the record from `Table#3` that has a "created date time" closest to the application "created date time" with out being after.

Note: `Table#1` has the `ID` which matches the records back to `Table#3`.  So, I have to join `Table#2` to `Table#1` then pick the record in `Table#3` which is closest in date time to the created date time in `Table#2`.

In example:

Table #2 - Record #1 - Created Date time @ 11/24/15 10:30:14

Table #3 - Record #1 - Created Date time @ 11/24/15 10:29:10

Table #3 - Record #2 - Created Date time @ 11/24/15 10:29:16

Table #3 - Record #3 - Created Date time @ 11/24/15 10:31:15

I want to join only `Table#3` - `Record#2` to `Table#2` - `Record#1`.  I want this record because it is the closest to the created date time in `Table#2`.

Also note, I need to use views when possible so others can use this data and not have to rely on me sending them updated code when updates occur.

I hope this makes sense, if not please ask me and I will help answer any more questions!  I HAVE to get this done or my boss is going to be very disappointed in my skill level.  He is not happy it has taken me this long to figure it out (2 days of running in circles). :-\

-Thanks ahead of time,

The guy less skilled than you

Answer (score 0):

try something on the lines of below structure, you will need to change it to use date differences and add the 3rd table as well..

```
select *
  from test1
      ,test2 
 where test1.a = test2.a
   and (test1.b - test2.c) = (
select min(t1.b - t2.c)
  from test1 t1
      ,test2 t2
 where t1.a = t2.a
   and test1.a = t1.a)
```